# Value of button in my react app doesn't change after i call hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

After the button in my react app is clicked three things happen a random sound is played from my library of dj khaled saying random words, the associated picture is rendered after an animation is played curtesy of frame-motion and afterward once the picture is rendered i want the button on the text to say clear so the user clears out the text and picture and generate a new one and the cycle happens again however the value of the button (text) does not change here is the associated code.

```
import "./center.css"
import {Howl,Howler} from "howler"
import { asparagus,cappucino,chandelier,tigerwoods,pic_asparagus,pic_cappucino,pic_chandelier,pic_tigerwoods } from "./import"
import Navbar from './nav'
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'
import { useState } from "react"


const sounds=[
  {sound : asparagus, label:"asparagus",image:pic_asparagus},
  {sound : cappucino, label:"cappucino",image:pic_cappucino},
  {sound : chandelier, label:"chandelier",image:pic_chandelier},
  {sound : tigerwoods, label:"tigerwoods",image:pic_tigerwoods},
]

const variants = {
  disappear : {
    opacity : 0  
  },
  appear : {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

var flagito=true;

function playsound(src)
{
  const sound = new Howl({src,html5:true})
  sound.play();
}

function Center()
{
  Howler.volume(1.0)
  const [flag , setFlag] = useState(true)
    return(
      <div className="center">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="main">
            <h2>Let dj Khaled names things</h2>
            <div className="mainmain">
              <motion.img
              variants={variants} 
              initial={{opacity: flag ? 1 :0}}
              animate={{opacity: flag ? 0 :1}}
              id="picture"/>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" className="inputtext" placeholder="The name" readOnly />
              <input type="button" value="Generate" className="inputbutton" id="btn" 
              onClick={()=>{
                if(flagito)
                {
                  setFlag(!flag)
                  const index=Math.floor(sounds.length*Math.random())
                  playsound(sounds[index].sound)
                  document.getElementById("name").value=sounds[index].label
                  document.getElementById("picture").setAttribute("src",sounds[index].image)
                  document.getElementById("btn").value='Degenerate'
                  flagito=!flagito;
                }
                else
                {
                  setFlag(!flag)
                  document.getElementById("name").value=''
                  document.getElementById("btn").value='Generate'
                  flagito=!flagito
                }
                console.log(document.getElementById("btn").value)
              }} 
              />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
}

export default Center
```

this is my first react app so it is probably not top notch but i can't for the life of me figure it out.
i tried removing the call to the hook function setFlag and that seems to allow the button to change values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing and manipulating the DOM directly, as you're doing with `document.getElementById`, is not recommended in React due to how React keeps track of the DOM and its own state.

I would recommend using state to set the button's text. So you'd add something like:

```
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Generate');
```

And in your `onClick` function you'd `setButtonText('Clear')` (or whatever the conditions warrant), the same way you're setting the flag state. In the place where you're actually telling the button what it's text is (looks like it's the `value` in this case?), you'll tell it to look at `buttonText`. That way it will update whenever `buttonText` does. You should be able to remove the direct use of `document` at this point.

I hope this helps, enjoy React!

Comment: Thank you so much that actually helped i totally forgot about the virtual DOM and how react handles all that but in retrospect the course i was watching on youtube did not dive too deep into that, speaking of which any course/website tounderstand more the theory and the abstractions of react.